# Joomla 2.5 - add automatic system message when user is logged in

Tags: authentication, system, message, joomla2.5

Joomla 2.5 does already generate a "you are logged in now" message, but only one time after a user just registered (if "auto-login" is enabled).

However I would like to display a similar (not exact same) message each time when the user loggs in (as a "greeting").

Any rough pointer of directions from anyone (e.g. where in the Joomla code to look how it's done in the "auto-login after registration" case) ?

THANKS guys (n' girls ;)

Comment: Can you explained a little more about where you want to put this message. You want something like a pop-up? OR something like Hello, User Name? Or a welcome message?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I am looking into various possibilities to present users who log into a website valuable information, but I dont want to overcomplicate things.

Comment: So you only want to customize the welcome message after they login right?

Comment: If u ask me what the best solution would be for me: redirect a logged-in user to a designated article/K2 ID whereby this redirect uses "target=_blank". I say that this would be ideal because calling a re-direct page allows to add all sorts of information within such a page (even "modules everywhere") and the _blank also would allow to let it nicely popup in a modal window using NoNumber.nl Modalizer. Understand? This way you could display upon login to any user pretty much any information in any style you want, nicely in a modal window. all thats needed is redirecting upon login using _blank.

Comment: Just to clarify before I'll try to help. 1 - redirect via _blank asfter pressing the login button | 2 - redirect to a k2 page using the nonumber plugins

Comment: the standard Joomla login module would need to be tweaked to let the "re-direct upon login" call the target using _blank. If you combine this modified login module with NoNumber.nl modalizer then you would display in a modal window whatever you add to that redirected article/K2 Item - mich more powerful than just reading the basic text string from an ini language file. Got me?  THANKS

Comment: Sure, so the user won't leave the page because you are redirecting to the modal. Am I getting the idea? So the _blank + modal would be the page after login.

Comment: yep, I added one more comment after your replied already explaining the scenario. Really, quite a small thing to add to the Joomla login module, with huge extra potential coz once you can re-direct to an article/K2 ID using _blank then u have a massive extra range of already existing (!) functionalities at your disposal using all the existing tools to display infos in articles/K2 item (as said, even "modules everywhere, also nonumbers.nl). this way, what u display upon login is only limited by ur imagination.

Comment: I just subscribed to your website's newsletter. If u want me to send u a link to a test website to try this simple functionality, I am happy to send you. You can easily turin this into a "product" (Joomla login module with the described functionality). Feel free to do so if u want, totally fine with me (if it also helps me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to write a plugin which hooks into "onUserLogin" to raise the warning.
More informations about plugin development can be found on JDocs http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin.